# Max number of classroom id retrieved

Tags: google-classroom

I have aprox 520 classrooms archived in my account, if I try to select them with

> var courseList = Classroom.Courses.list({"courseStates":["ARCHIVED"]}).courses;

I get only 300 of them. Is this normal?
How can I select them all? Actually I'm writing a script to delete the oldest, but if I can't retrieve them, I can't delete them.

Comment: A short solution should be to select corseStates: ARCHIVED and creationTime: a specified year and month (not the day because can be any). But I can't understand the syntax to obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you got so many courses that the [`Courses.list()`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) response is splitted in separate *pages*. In that case you can very easily navigate them by using tokens. First of all, make sure that you specify the `pageSize` in your request. That would set the desired amount of responses per page. Please keep in mind that the server may return fewer than the specified number of results, as it declared on the docs. In case that your response got divided into pages, the response would include the `nextPageToken` field. Then, to obtain the rest of courses, you have to repeat your request including that `nextPageToken` into the `pageToken` property. Please don't hesitate to ask me any doubt about this approach.

Comment: Hi Jacques, thanks for your answer. I was looking for docs about pageSize, but I can't find anything. Can you help me to understand the correct syntaxis?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Jaques, I found the solution:

```
  var parametri = {"courseStates": "ARCHIVED"};
  var page = Classroom.Courses.list(parametri);
  var listaClassi = page.courses;
  
  if (page.nextPageToken !== '') {
      parametri.pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
      page = Classroom.Courses.list(parametri);
      listaClassi = listaClassi.concat(page.courses);
  }
```

Anyway, I didn't need to change the pageSize, nor I found any tutorial about it.